# Custom two-column typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

Is it possible to do a really custom typeahead.js layout with two columns?

I'm implementing a person lookup. If the person isn't found or is of the wrong type, I want the user to be able to pick that option. The typeahead dropdown could look something like this:

```
jo
--------------------------------
| Joe     | Not found          |
| John    | Wrong type         |
| Joseph  | Some other problem |
| Jose    |                    |
--------------------------------
```

When the user types "jo", there is a list of matching people, and they can down-arrow and hit enter to pick one. Or the user can right-arrow to the right column, down-arrow to the appropriate problem, and hit enter.

Is this possible? All I see in the typeahead js documentation is the ability to have a custom template *per option*, but nothing about having multiple columns.

Comment: typeahead dropdown should be a div just as any other (I suppose), isn't it possible to style it with css as any other div?

Comment: So far as I can tell, each entry is a div, but it isn't clear to me how to style the dropdown as a whole.

Comment: I'd say, there should be anther enclosing parent div somewhere.. if not you can also add and customize that too probably but this can be tricky since you'd be forking the lib in some sort then..

Comment: Would it be possible to create a jsFiddle? That way it will be easier to update it and provide right answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the [example](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#custom-templates) for template rendering. Is this what you are looking for?

```
$('#custom-templates .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'best-pictures',
  display: 'value',
  source: bestPictures,
  templates: {
    empty: [
      '<div class="empty-message">',
        'unable to find any Best Picture winners that match the current query',
      '</div>'
    ].join('\n'),
    suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<div><strong>{{value}}</strong> – {{year}}</div>')
  }
});
```

Comment: That's only a single column. The custom template is only for a single row.